# How to convert SWF movie to MP4?

Tags: animation

I animate in Adobe Flash Professional CS5.5 on Windows 7. All my work exists in that version. The problem is that once I export an SWF Movie I can't convert it to MP4 with tools such as Swivel or other kind of online convert sites. (I know Adobe canceled Flash...) Is there any alternative way out there?

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you play the movie?  Could you use screen recording software to capture it? Are you sure you can't export as video from Flash?  It's really hard to offer advice here on very old software,  Also, video questions are technically off-topic here. Perhaps you'd get a better answer on Video Production Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. (I will try on Video Production aswell.) The only option for export as a moving picture on CS5.5 is currently "Export Movie". Atleast on my version. The "Export Video is missing". The movie plays in SWF Movie format. I havent't yet tried screen recording, no. I will try. Thank you for the help Billy!